# Use Ivy to get latest X.X.X.Final Hibernate

Tags: regex, hibernate, maven, ivy

I am using IvyDE in Eclipse and getting

```
unresolved dependency: org.hibernate#hibernate-core;final: not found
```

using code:

**ivysettings.xml**

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="maven2"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="maven2" m2compatible="true"/>
    </resolvers>
    <version-matchers>
        <pattern-vm>
            <match revision="final" pattern="\*Final" matcher="regexp"/>
        </pattern-vm>
    </version-matchers>
</ivysettings>
```

**ivy.xml**

```
...
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="final"/>
...
```

I have tried `rev="final()"` and get the same error. I am using http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/version-matchers.html as a guide.

I want to get the latest X.X.X.Final version of Hibernate.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression does not match any of revision numbers (You're looking for a non-existent "*" character).

Try this instead:

```
<version-matchers usedefaults="true">
    <pattern-vm>
        <match revision="final" pattern=".*Final$" matcher="regexp"/>
    </pattern-vm>
</version-matchers>
```

Comment: Thank you. I could not find a description of how regexp's should be formatted.

Comment: Mark, when I do this, "latest.integration" appears to break for my other dependencies. Does the pattern-vm tag override the default revision matchers?

Comment: @DuncanCalvert Try setting the "usedefaults" attribute on the "version-matchers" tag to true (defaults to false which might be the issue). See the doco: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/version-matchers.html