# Latest stable revision with ivy excluding alpha & beta releases

Tags: ivy

For our project we like to have most dependecies automaticaly up to date so we want to use the lastest strategies in IVY. However we dont want to run the bleeding edge of the dependencies ie. alpha and beta versions.

When using:

`<dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpclient" rev="latest.revision" />`

or

`<dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpclient" rev="latest.release" />`

We get revision `4.4-alpha1`

This is understandable as we use the ibiblio resolver which contains the following xml in maven-metadata.xml

`<metadata>
 <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
 <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
 <versioning>
   <latest>4.4-alpha1</latest>
   <release>4.4-alpha1</release>
   <versions>
    <version>4.0-alpha1</version>
<!-- snip --->
    <version>4.3-alpha1</version>
    <version>4.3-beta1</version>
    <version>4.3-beta2</version>
    <version>4.3</version>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
    <version>4.3.3</version>
    <version>4.3.4</version>
    <version>4.3.5</version>
    <version>4.4-alpha1</version>
   </versions>
   <lastUpdated>20140801101402</lastUpdated>
 </versioning>
</metadata>`

The meta data indicates the alpha version as both release and latest. (not sure if this is related actualy)

In this case we there is a version we would like to get in the metadata list being `4.3.5`

Now ivy has a construct with  and  but the documentation is quite sparse, and i cant figure out how to make this strategy 'ignore' the alpha release.

I tried variation of the following to no avail (using `rev="latest.test"`) : 
`

Edit:
From the source code of `org.apache.ivy.plugins.latest.LatestRevisionStrategy` it appears specialmeanings wont be able to solve this since the version is first split in parts and then compared on a part by part basis.

If there is a way to forbid revisions that contain a specific string my problem would also be solved.
`

Comment: Auto-updating a dependency is not necessarily a great idea - that is, if you use such an auto-updating dependency in your build definitions, then your build results become time-dependent, which can lead to a cascade of issues.

Comment: i understand these risks, but this is something we want specificaly want (not for all libraries ofcourse). The main reason being to automatically stay up to data and have only minor regression from time to time (we have some 300 libs to keep up to date)

Answer (score 4):

The source code of org.apache.ivy.plugins.latest.LatestRevisionStrategy indicated it's impossible to fix this with special-meaning strings in a latestStrategy element. (thanks to: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394646/use-ivy-to-get-latest-x-x-x-final-hibernate))

we ended up using a version matcher to enforse ivy to not use -beta- or -alpha releases.
Its not an optimal solution and the regexp probably needs to be updated a few times still.

in ivysettings.xml:

```
<version-matchers usedefaults="true">
    <pattern-vm name="lastest.nobeta">
        <match  revision="latest.nobeta" pattern="\.*\d+\.\d+\.?\d*(FINAL|RELEASE|STABLE)?"  matcher="regexp" />
    </pattern-vm>
</version-matchers>
```

and in ivy.xml:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.poi" name="poi" rev="latest.nobeta"/>
```

Not entirely sure if this takes the lastest version but so far that seems to be the case.

Comment: How does Ivy know that it should take the latest revision? The pattern does not state anything about that.

Comment: not sure atm (long time ago) but i think the custom pattern either inherits from the existing "latest" or it cascaded (might be because of the usedefaults=true)

Comment: Ok, I asked on one of the Ivy Jira tickets and one contributor gave me a quite good [answer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-871?focusedCommentId=16288778&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16288778) to this question.